# Django User Model Require First and Last Names

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I know there are many related questions on SO concerning the extension of the user model. In my case, I'm using `django-allauth` with a `CustomUser` model which inherits from `AbstractUser`. I would like to use all the functionality of the built in `User` model, since everything works well enough. I simply want to make the `first_name` and `last_name` fields required by overriding the existing `blank = True` on these model fields.

Some suggestions I've seen include ignoring the built in fields and just use new ones in my custom model. That seems counter to the Python and Django way.

My goal was to do this at DB/model level since that would cascade the validation through the existing forms.

Is there a way to override `blank=True` for these two model fields? I would like theses two fields to be required, and otherwise adhere to the existing `AbstractUser` requirements.

**Edit**
Answers suggested this result which has the desired behavior. I added these lines to my model:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? How would I do that when the fields are already defined in the `AbstractUser` class.

Comment: I added in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `null=True` it works database level.
Example:

```
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
```

1. **null**: It is database-related. Defines if a given database column
   will accept null values or not.
2. **blank**: It is validation-related. It
   will be used during forms validation when calling form.is_valid().

Comment: I didn't think you could override fields just by defining them again, but I guess it works for methods.

Comment: Is there a way to call `super()` to otherwise leave the definition as in the original model?

Comment: You need to make `first_name` as optional means when you not provide value for this, it shuldn't shows any validation error. Isn't it?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I would like `first_name` and `last_name` required and not null. I see the original field was quite basic
`first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)`
`last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=150, blank=True)`

Comment: then try this `first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)`

Comment: also make sure after the change you run `makemigrations` and `migrate` command

Answer (score 1):

Just **override** **first_name** and **last_name** field as below and make them null=True, blank=True

```
CustomUser(AbstractUser):
     first_name= models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
     last_name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
     .........
     .........
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to those fiels be required, you need to override first_name and last_name field as below and make them null=False, blank=False:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    ...

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return'{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

And if you want to your admin's registration page include theses fields:

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):

    ...

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2')
        }),
    )
```